# What does Vader's HUD say in Revenge of the Sith?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

Near the end of *Revenge of the Sith* Anakin's burned and mutilated body was retrieved by Palpatine and taken to a hospital.  Prosthetics were attached to Anakin's stumps and Vader's familiar mask and cowl were put into place for the first time.  As the mask descended some text and graphics could be seen on the insides of the eye lenses, suggesting an information display of some kind.

[image: inside view of Vader's mask]

The text is indistinct on the standard DVD version of the movie.  Now that the Blu-Ray version has been released perhaps the increased resolution has made the text readable.  Can anyone read the text and post what it says here?  The script might not be in any human language, so an image with a clear view of the script would be an acceptable answer in that case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'll give it a go from my HD copy. Keep in mind that the text does change, so it depends on when the screenshot is taken.

Reading from left to right, top to bottom. I've numbered in lime green the sets.

**Left lens:**

First set: Nine, capital Z, one, that angle symbol, omega?, capital E, blurred cent symbol.

Second set: One, seven, one, blurred four, square, seven, niner.

Third set: Warped capital M, percent sign, rattle snake, puppy, right foot, one, puppy.

Fourth set: Guitar pic, three, niner.

Fifth set: Three, reversed capital S, blurred thing, spaceship, round blur, round blur, round blur.

Sixth set: Warped capital M, a bunch of blurred stuff, more blur, and more blur.

[image: Left lense]

---

**Right lens:**

First set: Three, blur, hidden stuff, duck, triangle, capital Z, one, that angle symbol, spaceship, cursive capital L, capital U that's broken, warped capital M.

Second set: Nine, capital H, seven, one, four, zero, seven.

Third set: Capital M, blurred M, one, reversed upside-down one, capital W.

Fourth set: Capital P, three, seven.

Fifth set: Warped capital M, three, zero, capital W, upside-down triangle, triangle, capital W.

Sixth set: Blurred capital P, three, seven.

Seventh set: Warped capital M, percent sign, super long snake, left foot, spaceship, puppy.

[image: Right lense]

I could be wrong. Sorry if this isn't much help...

Comment: So largely garbage.... Could you number the sets in the images so we can follow them?

Comment: Hoped for something interesting, but thanks for the images anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The text is in Aurabesh script. The alphabet used for Star Wars basic.
While I can make out some characters, I can't make out all of them.
Here is the entire alphabet:

[image]

Comment: Could you edit what letters you can see on the HUD into your answer?

Comment: So not English, but not necessarily garbage either.  Interesting.